# How to generate understanding of PLSQL package, procedure or function?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

we can generate ER diagram in SQL developer which help us in understanding of tables in a better way.

Like this Is it possible we can generate some kind of document which can give us overview of what a package/procedure/function is doing?

I'm asking this because in my project we have very long packages like 10000 lines and to read them consume lot of time. If we can generate some kind of document for understanding it will be very helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as my experience is concerned there is no tool available which will generate documentation out of PLSQL code (just by reading the code without any comments).

However, I would like to mention the following tools and you can consider using them if they are of any help.

**Pldoc**

Pldoc is an open-source utility for generating HTML documentation of code written in Oracle PL/SQL.

http://pldoc.sourceforge.net/maven-site/

However, you will have to provide comments in your packages and functions in PLdoc style to ensure that documentation gets created.

**Toad's Code Xpert**

http://www.toadworld.com/products/toad-for-oracle/w/toad_for_oracle_wiki/11088.code-complexity-analysis-using-toad

This tool will perform an automated review on your code and provide a report. It will also provide a CRUD matrix which you might find useful.

**PLSQL Doc Plugin**
https://www.allroundautomations.com/plsplsqldoc.html

Similar to PLdoc.

**Natural Docs**

http://www.naturaldocs.org/

Open-source documentation generator for multiple programming languages.

Comment: Thanks, this will help.

Answer (score 1):

There is no silver bullet - you cannot automagically create documentation for code. 
Worse - the "auto-doc" tools typically look at comments, but there's no guarantee the comments match the code.

However, ["working with legacy code"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/122014/what-are-the-key-points-of-working-effectively-with-legacy-code) is a common problem. You might want to read this answer, and the book it refers to.

Answer (score 0):

I'm happy with this (new) tool: https://github.com/teotiger/pldocu

It's limited and I miss some automatic export formats (e.g. html), but you can try to do this by yourself. For me it's okay.